# Inconsistent results trying to get window handles from the process ID

Tags: delphi, winapi

I am trying to host other applications in a Delphi form, but I am finding my routine to get the window handles is inconsistent.

If I start notepad.exe for example the routine below does not find any window handles matching the process ID. However other applications (such as my own Delphi built apps) are found. This routine is based on many examples that I have found but I cannot figure out what I am missing.

```
function enum_windows_callback(Handle: HWND; LParam: longint): bool; stdcall;
begin
  Result := true;
  var obj: TfHostApplication := TfHostApplication(Pointer(lParam)^);
  var process_id: Cardinal := 0;
  GetWindowThreadProcessId(Handle, &process_id);
  if (obj.process_id = process_id) and (handle <> 0) then //and is_main_window(handle) then
    obj.AppWindowHandles.Add(handle);
end;

procedure TfHostApplication.HostApplication(fn: string);
var
  Rec: TShellExecuteInfo;
  Title: string;
const
  AVerb = 'open';
  AParams = '';
  ADir = '';
begin
  FillChar(Rec, SizeOf(Rec), #0);

  Rec.cbSize       := SizeOf(Rec);
  Rec.fMask        := SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS;
  Rec.lpVerb       := PChar( AVerb );
  Rec.lpFile       := PChar( fn );
  Rec.lpParameters := PChar( AParams );
  Rec.lpDirectory  := PChar( Adir );
  Rec.nShow        := SW_HIDE;

  // Run the application
  if ShellExecuteEx(@Rec) then
  begin
    // Wait for it to become ideal i.e. finished loading
    WaitForInputIdle(Rec.hProcess, 5000);
    // Get the list of window handles for this process
    AppWindowHandles.Clear;
    ProcessHandle := Rec.hProcess;
    process_id := GetProcessId(Rec.hProcess);
    EnumWindows(@enum_windows_callback, integer(@Self));
    if AppWindowHandles.Count > 1 then
    begin
      // if there is more than 1 window then display a list for the user to choose
      lbWindows.Items.Clear;
      var def := 0;
      for var hwd in AppWindowHandles do
      begin
        var Len := GetWindowTextLength(hwd) + 1;
        SetLength(Title, Len);
        GetWindowText(hwd, PChar(Title), Len);
        Title := Trim(Title);
        lbWindows.Items.Add(Title);
      end;
      PanelSel.Visible := true;
      PanelSel.align := alClient;
    end
    else if AppWindowHandles.Count > 0 then
    begin
      // if there is only 1 window then just use this.
      SelectedWindowHandle := AppWindowHandles[0];
      ShowAppInWindow;
    end
    else
      DoCloseView;
  end;
end;

procedure TfHostApplication.lbWindowsClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  inherited;
  PanelSel.Visible := false;
  if lbWindows.ItemIndex < AppWindowHandles.Count then
  begin
    SelectedWindowHandle := AppWindowHandles[lbWindows.ItemIndex];
    SelectedWindowName := lbWindows.Items[lbWindows.ItemIndex];
    ShowAppInWindow;
  end;
end;

procedure TfHostApplication.ShowAppInWindow;
begin
  Windows.SetParent(SelectedWindowHandle, Handle );

  var Style := GetWindowLongPtr(SelectedWindowHandle, GWL_STYLE);
  Style := Style and (not (WS_BORDER + WS_DLGFRAME + WS_THICKFRAME));
  SetWindowLongPtr(SelectedWindowHandle, GWL_STYLE, Style);

  Resize;
  ShowWindow(SelectedWindowHandle, SW_SHOW);
end;
```

Comment: `&process_id` is not Delphi.

Comment: `GetWindowThreadProcessId(Handle, &process_id);` is exactly equivalent to `GetWindowThreadProcessId(Handle, process_id);`. In Delphi, `&` is used to make reserved words usable as identifiers, like `var &begin := 6;`. In this case, `process_id` is not a Pascal or Delphi reserved word, so `&process_id` should be written simply `process_id`. Martin is probably thinking about the `@` (address of) operator: `@process_id`. Now, the `GetWindowThreadProcessId` function is overloaded: one variant takes a ptr, the other a `var`. So actually `process_id`, `&process_id`, and `@process_id` all work!

Comment: Here's a bug: `EnumWindows(@enum_windows_callback, integer(@Self));`. Actually, there are two problems: First, you mean `Self`, not `@Self`, since in Delphi, object variables like `Self` *ARE* pointers. Second, `Integer(Self)` will take a native-sized pointer (Self) and truncate it to a 32-bit `Integer`. This is perfectly fine in a 32-bit app, but is a bug in a 64-bit app. I mean, if you take a 64-digit phone number and replace the first 32 digits with zeros, it may no longer work. You need `NativeInt(Self)` (or, equivalently, `LPARAM(Self)`).

Comment: Also, the declaration `enum_windows_callback(Handle: HWND; LParam: longint)` is wrong. `LParam` must be a `LPARAM`, or a `NativeInt` (32-bit in 32-bit app; 64-bit in 64-bit app). `LONGINT` is always 32-bit. So again you will corrupt memory in a 64-bit app (and any future 128-bit Windows app).

Comment: And `TfHostApplication(Pointer(lParam)^)` should be `TfHostApplication(Pointer(lParam))` which is the same thing as `TfHostApplication(lParam)`. No need to compensate for the previous unnecessary indirection that's now removed.

Comment: Cross process parenting isn't something you can expect to work. You should give up now and find a solution to your problem that you can expect to work.

Comment: [Is it legal to have a cross-process parent/child or owner/owned window relationship?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130412-00/?p=4683)

Comment: The dangers of being a Delphi & C++ developer. @RemyLebeau - noted your comment but I am keen to pursue this a bit further.

Comment: Interestingly I have discovered that "FindWindow('Notepad', 0)" does work to find Notepad.exe  window handle so I am more confused as to why EnumWindows does not. 
In the case of notepad.exe (just a test app and not one I expect end user to select) it will host the application and you see it for about a second and then it disappears.

Comment: @Martin do you have the same problem if you use `CreateProcess()` (which gives you both process ID and process handle) instead of `ShellExecuteEx()`+`GetProcessId()`? Also, you are leaking the `Rec.hProcess` handle. You need to call `CloseHandle()` on it when you are done using it.

Comment: @RemyLebeau you are correct that CreateProcess works significantly better than ShellExecute. This appears to be the solution to getting this working reliably.

Answer (score 0):

Using CreateProcess rather than SheelExecute appears to solve the issues with finding the handle.

```
function TfHostApplication.StartApplication(fn: string): Cardinal;
var
  StartupInfo: TStartupInfo;
  Command: string;
begin
  Result := 0;
  FillChar(StartupInfo, SizeOf(TStartupInfo), 0);
  StartupInfo.cb := SizeOf(TStartupInfo);
  StartupInfo.dwFlags := STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
  StartupInfo.wShowWindow := SW_HIDE;
  Command := '"' + fn + '"';
  if CreateProcess(nil, PChar(Command), nil, nil, False, 0, nil, nil, StartupInfo, ProcessInfo) then
  begin
    ProcessHandle := ProcessInfo.hProcess;
    Result := ProcessInfo.dwProcessId;
  end;
end;

procedure TfHostApplication.HostApplication(fn: string);
var
  Title: string;
begin
  process_id := StartApplication(fn);
  if process_id > 0 then
  begin
    // Wait for it to become ideal i.e. finished loading
    WaitForInputIdle(ProcessInfo.hProcess, 5000);
    WaitForSingleObject(ProcessInfo.hProcess, 5000);
    // Get the list of window handles for this process
    AppWindowHandles.Clear;
    SelectedWindowHandle := Windows.FindWindow(PWideChar(TPath.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(FAppFileName)), nil );
    if SelectedWindowHandle <> 0 then
      ShowAppInWindow
    else
    begin
      EnumWindows(@enum_windows_callback, NativeInt(Self));
      if AppWindowHandles.Count > 1 then
      begin
        // if there is more than 1 window then display a list for the user to choose
        lbWindows.Items.Clear;
        var def := 0;
        for var hwd in AppWindowHandles do
        begin
          var Len := GetWindowTextLength(hwd) + 1;
          SetLength(Title, Len);
          GetWindowText(hwd, PChar(Title), Len);
          Title := Trim(Title);
          lbWindows.Items.Add(Title);
        end;
        // Check to see if the selected window is already in the parameters
        var sIdx := lbWindows.Items.IndexOf(FSelectedWindowName);
        if (sIdx > -1) and (sIdx < AppWindowHandles.Count) then
        begin
          SelectedWindowHandle := AppWindowHandles[sIdx];
          ShowAppInWindow;
        end
        else
        begin
          PanelSel.Visible := true;
          PanelSel.align := alClient;
        end;
      end
      else if AppWindowHandles.Count > 0 then
      begin
        // if there is only 1 window then just use this.
        SelectedWindowHandle := AppWindowHandles[0];
        ShowAppInWindow;
      end
      else
        DoCloseView;
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TfHostApplication.lbWindowsClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  inherited;
  PanelSel.Visible := false;
  if (lbWindows.ItemIndex > -1) and (lbWindows.ItemIndex < AppWindowHandles.Count) then
  begin
    SelectedWindowHandle := AppWindowHandles[lbWindows.ItemIndex];
    SelectedWindowName := lbWindows.Items[lbWindows.ItemIndex];
    ShowAppInWindow;
  end;
end;

procedure TfHostApplication.ShowAppInWindow;
begin
  // Set the window parent
  Windows.SetParent(SelectedWindowHandle, Handle );

  var Style := GetWindowLongPtr(SelectedWindowHandle, GWL_STYLE);
  Style := Style and (not (WS_BORDER + WS_DLGFRAME + WS_THICKFRAME));
  SetWindowLongPtr(SelectedWindowHandle, GWL_STYLE, Style);

  Resize;
  ShowWindow(SelectedWindowHandle, SW_SHOW);
  BringWindowToTop(SelectedWindowHandle);
end;
```

Answer (score -4):

> If I start notepad.exe for example the routine below does not find any window handles matching the process ID

The reason for this is the fact that on a 64 bit version of Windows a 64 bit version of Notepad is started by default. And since your program is 32 bit you can not access process information from any 64 bit application/process.

You need to use a 64 bit version of your application in order to retrieve process information from 64 bit applications.

Note: you can manually start a 32 bit version of Notepad that is located in `\Windows\SysWOW64` folder.

Comment: Cannot reproduce: on Win7x64 using D7x32 Notepad x32 is started. Executing `\Program Files\Notepad++\Notepad++.exe` (x64) works and getting its top level windows, too.

Comment: @AmigoJack You are talking here about `Notepad++.exe` while OP is most likely talking about `Notepad.exe` that ships with Windows.

Comment: This is a 64bit app

Comment: "*[a 32bit application/process] can not access process information from any 64 bit application/process*" - that is completely wrong. Not to mention that the only "process information" being accessed here are HWNDs and PIDs, which are freely accessible/exchangable between 32bit and 64bit processes.

Comment: Of course I'm talking about _Notepad++_ because that's for sure an x64 program I was able to start through my x32 program as opposed to `notepad.exe` that would be redirected to x32 even when I would use the path to its x64 counterpart - that's the whole point. Do you think I'm an idiot? And who upvoted that comment? It's a coincidence that it's _Notepad++_ - just think of any other truly x64 program like `thunderbird.exe` or `WinMergeU.exe` or `Wireshark.exe` or whatever is known to you. Any x32 program can start any x64 program.